# Chaincode events in hyperledger fabric do not call the currently registered event

Tags: events, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to use chaincode events in Hyperledger Fabric v1.3.0. It calls the chaincode event registered on the previous invoke-transaction call(I want it to call the current one). 
I am using the balance-transfer sdk layer with modifications(provided in fabric-samples).
Here is the snippet of invoke-transaction.js that I modified -

```
var promises = [];
        let event_hubs = channel.getChannelEventHubsForOrg();
        event_hubs.forEach((eh) => {
            eh.connect(true);
            let invokeCCEventPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let event_timeout1 = setTimeout(() => {
                    let message = 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT:' + eh.getPeerAddr();
                    logger.error(message);
                    eh.disconnect();
                }, 3000);

                regid = eh.registerChaincodeEvent(chaincodeName, 'evtsender*', (event, block_num, txnid, status) => {
                        // This callback will be called when there is a chaincode event name
                        // within a block that will match on the second parameter in the registration
                        // from the chaincode with the ID of the first parameter.
                        console.log('Successfully got a chaincode event with transid:' + txnid + ' with status:' + status);


                        // to see the event payload, the channel_event_hub must be connected(true)
                        let event_payload = event.payload.toString('utf8');
                        logger.info('Event Payload: ', event_payload);

                        if (event_payload.indexOf('code') > -1) {
                            clearTimeout(event_timeout1);
                            // Chaincode event listeners are meant to run continuously
                            // Therefore the default to automatically unregister is false
                            // So in this case we want to shutdown the event listener once
                            // we see the event with the correct payload
                            eh.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                            console.log('Successfully received the chaincode event on block number ' + block_num);
                            resolve('RECEIVED');
                        } else {
                            console.log('Successfully got chaincode event ... just not the one we are looking for on block number ' + block_num);
                        }
                    }, (error) => {
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout1);
                        console.log('Failed to receive the chaincode event ::' + error);
                        reject(error);
                    },
                    // no options specified
                    // startBlock will default to latest
                    // endBlock will default to MAX
                    // unregister will default to false
                    // disconnect will default to false
                    {
                        unregister: true
                    }

                );

            });
            promises.push(invokeCCEventPromise);





            logger.debug('invokeEventPromise - setting up event');
            let invokeEventPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                let event_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                    let message = 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT:' + eh.getPeerAddr();
                    logger.error(message);
                    eh.disconnect();
                }, 3000);
                eh.registerTxEvent(tx_id_string, (tx, code, block_num) => {
                        logger.info('The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer %s', eh.getPeerAddr());
                        logger.info('Transaction %s has status of %s in block %s', tx, code, block_num);
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);

                        if (code !== 'VALID') {
                            let message = util.format('The invoke chaincode transaction was invalid, code:%s', code);
                            logger.error(message);
                            reject(new Error(message));
                        } else {
                            let message = 'The invoke chaincode transaction was valid.';
                            logger.info(message);
                            resolve(message);
                        }
                    }, (err) => {
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout);
                        logger.error(err);
                        reject(err);
                    },
                    // the default for 'unregister' is true for transaction listeners
                    // so no real need to set here, however for 'disconnect'
                    // the default is false as most event hubs are long running
                    // in this use case we are using it only once
                    {
                        unregister: true,
                        disconnect: true
                    }
                );
                eh.connect();
            });
            promises.push(invokeEventPromise);
        });

        var orderer_request = {
            txId: tx_id,
            proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
            proposal: proposal
        };
        var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(orderer_request);
        // put the send to the orderer last so that the events get registered and
        // are ready for the orderering and committing
        promises.push(sendPromise);
        let results = await Promise.all(promises);
```

My understanding of the problem-
Events are registered and stored in blocks.
Fabric starts searching for registered events from the 'last block' in the chain unless specified explicitly in the [,OPTIONS] parameter.
Fabric calls the 'chaincode event' before the current block is committed on the ledger resultig it in finding on the previous block.
This is unlike the 'TxEvent' which is called after the block has been committed.
I need the 'chaincode event' to get called just after the current transaction has been committed as I need to call another function using the parameters from 'payload'.
Is this intended? Is there a workaround for this?

Please point out if my understanding is wrong in any way. I am still learning to use Fabric.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive the currently emitted chaincodeEvent, call the 'registerChaincodeEvent' function inside the registerTxEvent i.e once the transaction event is received, it means the transaction has been committed on the peer. Now you can get the current chaincode event. You can modify your code as written below:

```
        logger.debug('invokeEventPromise - setting up event');
        let invokeEventPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let event_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                let message = 'REQUEST_TIMEOUT:' + eh.getPeerAddr();
                logger.error(message);
                eh.disconnect();
            }, 3000);
            eh.registerTxEvent(tx_id_string, (tx, code, block_num) => {
                    logger.info('The chaincode invoke chaincode transaction has been committed on peer %s', eh.getPeerAddr());
                    logger.info('Transaction %s has status of %s in block %s', tx, code, block_num);
                    clearTimeout(event_timeout);

                    if (code !== 'VALID') {
                        let message = util.format('The invoke chaincode transaction was invalid, code:%s', code);
                        logger.error(message);
                        reject(new Error(message));
                    } else {
                        let message = 'The invoke chaincode transaction was valid.';
                        logger.info(message);


            regid = eh.registerChaincodeEvent(chaincodeName, 'evtsender*', (event, block_num, txnid, status) => {
                    // This callback will be called when there is a chaincode event name
                    // within a block that will match on the second parameter in the registration
                    // from the chaincode with the ID of the first parameter.
                    console.log('Successfully got a chaincode event with transid:' + txnid + ' with status:' + status);


                    // to see the event payload, the channel_event_hub must be connected(true)
                    let event_payload = event.payload.toString('utf8');

                    logger.info('Event Payload: ', event_payload);
                    //do something with the payload
                    if (event_payload.indexOf('code') > -1) {
                        clearTimeout(event_timeout1);
                        // Chaincode event listeners are meant to run continuously
                        // Therefore the default to automatically unregister is false
                        // So in this case we want to shutdown the event listener once
                        // we see the event with the correct payload
                        eh.unregisterChaincodeEvent(regid);
                        console.log('Successfully received the chaincode event on block number ' + block_num);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Successfully got chaincode event ... just not the one we are looking for on block number ' + block_num);
                    }
                }, (error) => {
                    clearTimeout(event_timeout1);
                    console.log('Failed to receive the chaincode event ::' + error);
                },
                // no options specified
                // startBlock will default to latest
                // endBlock will default to MAX
                // unregister will default to false
                // disconnect will default to false
                {
                    unregister: true,
                    disconnect: true
                }

            );

                        resolve(message);
                    }
                }, (err) => {
                    clearTimeout(event_timeout);
                    logger.error(err);
                    reject(err);
                },
                // the default for 'unregister' is true for transaction listeners
                // so no real need to set here, however for 'disconnect'
                // the default is false as most event hubs are long running
                // in this use case we are using it only once
                {
                    unregister: true,
                    disconnect: false
                }
            );
            eh.connect();
        });
        promises.push(invokeEventPromise);
    });

    var orderer_request = {
        txId: tx_id,
        proposalResponses: proposalResponses,
        proposal: proposal
    };
    var sendPromise = channel.sendTransaction(orderer_request);
    // put the send to the orderer last so that the events get registered and
    // are ready for the orderering and committing
    promises.push(sendPromise);
    let results = await Promise.all(promises);
```